# How to send an array as a JSON string in postman body?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, api, postman

I'm trying to send some body data in my api call using postman.
(I'm using the "raw" body option)

My data in the body is like so:

```
{
 "products" : [{"id": 1, "quantity" : 2, "comments": "none"}]
}
```

Problem is, when I send the json body data containing an array, i get an error saying

```
The Products must be a valid JSON string
```

I have set my headers to content-type: application/json, but nothing is working,
am I missing something?

Comment: You did something wrong in your code

Comment: It's already a valid JSON. Probably you have mispelled the keys or another things in your code

Answer (score -2):

Your JSON is valid.

This should work for you:

```
var request = {
      method: "POST",
      url: "http://example.com/api",
      headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
      },
      body: "{\"products\":[{\"id\":1,\"quantity\":1,\"comments\":\"none\"},{\"id\":2,\"quantity\":3,\"comments\":\"Super good product\"},{\"id\":3,\"quantity\":6,\"comments\":\"not so good product\"}]}"
});
```

Comment: `request` is just an object and doesn't do anything by itself. What do you mean by it "should work", and what does it fix to make it work?